# aspects are not working in my spring project

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-aop

About Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PostAop{

    @Around("execution(* com.blog.controllers.PostController.add(..)) && args(request,..)")
    public String Authorized(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, HttpServletRequest request) throws Throwable {
```

And for annotation class:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD) // can use in method only.
public @interface Authorized {

    public boolean Admin() default true;
    public boolean Writer() default false;

}
```

And finaly this is my aspect configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.blog" })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AspectConfig {
    @Bean
    public PostAop postAop(){
        return new PostAop();
    }
}
```

And this is PostController class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"","/post"})
public class PostController {
         ...
    @GetMapping("/add")
    @Authorized(Writer = true)
    public String add(ModelMap model,Article article,HttpSession session) {

        model.addAttribute("tags", tagService.getAllTags());
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.getAllUsers());
        model.addAttribute("post", post);
        return "post/add";
    }
```

I actually don't know were is the probleme, I don't get any exception while running application but my aspect class PostAop never get called. Did i miss something in the configuration??

Comment: Please share the controller class code which should be adviced .

Comment: @R.G i added it in the main post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointcut expression

```
@Around("execution(* com.blog.controllers.PostController.add(..)) && args(request,..)")
```

can be explained as , advice a joinpoint (method execution in case of Spring AOP) which matches the following condition

execution of a method `com.blog.controllers.PostController.add` of any return type (*) and any arguments (..)

and

that method should have `HttpServletRequest request` as its first argument

Now in your `PostController` the method `add(ModelMap model,Article article,HttpSession session)` will not match the pointcut expression

The pointcut expression would work if you remove the `args(request,..)` and you can access the HttpServletRequest as follows

```
@Around("execution(* com.blog.controllers.PostController.add(..)) && within(com.blog.controllers..*)")
public String authorized(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
            .getRequest();
    return (String) jp.proceed();
}
```

`within()` is a scoping designator to narrow the scope of classes to advice.

Note :

When you annotate the `Aspect` class with `@Component` , it will be autodetected by the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.blog" })` if the `PostAop` is placed at any level under the root package `com.blog` . This means you dont have to create the bean using factory method and `@Bean` annotation. Either one of `@Component` or `@Bean` is required.

By java naming convention the name of the method will be `authroized()` and not `Authorized()`

Hope this helps.